# Convert Google Maps url to iFrame

Tags: c#, .net, regex, google-maps, iframe

I want to convert a Google map URL to embed iframe so that I can show it to html.
For example take this url:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/United+States/@37.2571807,-104.6682976,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742?hl=en

When you go to this url and click "Share" Google gives you the embed map url in iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d13007260.396144057!2d-104.66829755128677!3d37.257180679921!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x54eab584e432360b%3A0x1c3bb99243deb742!2sUnited+States!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1459600802389" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My Query is how to parse the url "https://www.google.com/maps/place/United+States/@37.2571807,-104.6682976,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x54eab584e432360b:0x1c3bb99243deb742?hl=en" and convert it to iframe one?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *parse* that URL to get the share `iframe`. If you compare the two, the data is DIFFERENT.

[Try the API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#overview)

You can then use this regex: `@(-?\d*[.]?\d*,-?\d*[.]?\d*),(\d)z`.

The URL will be `https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view
?key=YOUR_API_KEY
&center=$1
&zoom=$2
&maptype=satellite`, where `$1` and `$2` are from the regex.